# USB device (Mouse receiver) not recognised

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, mouse

I have a Logitech MX 1100 wireless mouse. The receiver suddenly stopped working.

It was working just fine when I turned off the computer last night. On turning it on again approximately 14 hours later, I got an error message saying USB device was not recognised.

All other USB devices are working fine.

I have a notebook with a removable battery and tried doing a hard reset as suggested on some forums online. That did not work. Notebook is a Dell XPS L502X with Windows 7.

This receiver is a month old replacement bought from Amazon as I lost the original while moving around.

Is this problem fixable?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably fixable.

I can't really find any similar problems on Google with the original receiver. Is it an exact match to the receiver that comes with the mouse, new?

If so, try reinstalling the drivers and replacing the batteries. If not, find an exact replacement.

Other than that, I don't think there's much you can do.